# CoreWebView2 returned null

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

I am working on a custom web browser project, but when I try to navigate by using this code, the project generates an error.

```cs
    (Controls["webView21"]  as WebView2).CoreWebView2.Navigate("URL goes here");
```

It said that `CoreWebView2` returned `null` even though I modified the `source` property without error. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is this code executed before the control is fully intialized/loaded? It has been a while, but there also should be a way to await the webview to be initialized, but it does require the control in which it has ben hosted to be also loaded. (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: No, it is called after the WebView2 is added to Controls.

Comment: Why do you have `Controls["webView21"]` instead of, e.g.,  `webView21.Source = [URL]`? -- Also, can you show the initialization procedure?

Comment: I tried using the root variable, but it threw a `NullReferenceException` if I didn't access it directly from Controls.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your initialization procedure.

Comment: Have you tried the samples they have provided and walked through the logic? You may see where you have gone amiss.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the `EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` method before accessing the `CoreWebView2` property:

```
var webViewControl = Controls["webView21"] as WebView2;
await webViewControl.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
webViewControl.CoreWebView2.Navigate("URL goes here");
```

Comment: This code is floating on thin air...

Comment: Because it's not exactly clear (to All) how / when / where this code is called.

Comment: It depends on the context obviously. The suggestion is event more obviously to "call the EnsureCoreWebView2Async() method before accessing the CoreWebView2 property". What's your point?

Comment: Quite simple: there's an `async` method you're awaiting. This needs to be called from another `async` method. The Context is the initialization of a Form Container, which in turn needs to initialize the underlying CoreWebView2 of a WebView2 Control. Which is probably the issue the OP has. If done incorrectly, using e.g., a non `async` method (something you can see relatively often in relation to WebView2, at SO and other *places*), then you have a problem. -- You can simply specify (possibly in code) when / where the OP should call this code.

Comment: From my code snippet, it's obvious that it's needs to be called in an `async` method. Otherwise it won't compile. If the OP has any further questions, I assume I will get a comment about that.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. It worked correctly.